# AngularJS slide transition

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

I'm trying to slide in a div and slide out another from left to right.

```
<div class="moveleft" ng-switch="article">
    <div ng-switch-when="1">
    ...hi... 
    </div>

    <div ng-switch-when="2">
    ...bye...       
     </div>
</div>
```

I want to do this sliding on a `button` click:

```
<button ng-click="changeori()">Hi</button>
```

In my AngularJS file:

```
$scope.article = 1;
$scope.changeori = function() {
    $scope.article = $scope.article == 1 ? 2 : 1;
}
```

And for my `moveleft` class:

```
.moveleft, .moveright {
    transition: 2000ms cubic-bezier(0.420, 0.000, 0.580, 1.000) all;
}

.moveleft.ng-enter {
   left: 100%;
}
.moveleft.ng-enter-active {
    left: 0;
}
.moveleft.ng-leave {
    left: 0;
}
.moveleft.ng-leave-active {
    left: -100%;
}
```

**Problem**: On clicking the button, the first div hides after 2 seconds and the second div comes on the click as expected, but the animations for slide are not happening.

Comment: create a fiddle if possible

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/01LwLntx/

Answer (score 0):

You are probably using the ng-animate wrong.

See this [working demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/Eu1QsSuOP1ZO00hYHn52?p=preview)

2 items(div) respond through animation css as below

```
.item {
    position: absolute;
    top: 35px;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    animation-duration: 0.30s;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.30s;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}

.item.ng-enter {
    animation-name: slideFromRight;
    -webkit-animation-name: slideFromRight;
}
.item.moveToLeft.ng-enter {
    animation-name: slideFromLeft;
    -webkit-animation-name: slideFromLeft;
}
.item.ng-leave {
    animation-name: slideFromLeft;
    animation-direction: reverse;
    -webkit-animation-name: slideFromLeft;
    -webkit-animation-direction: reverse;
}
.item.moveToLeft.ng-leave {
    animation-name: slideFromRight;
    animation-direction: reverse;
    -webkit-animation-name: slideFromRight;
    -webkit-animation-direction: reverse;
}
```